# ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1 (GitLab)

Tags: gitlab, cicd, devsecops

I'm taking a course on GitLab. job displays an error "ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1"?

Job in .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
dast-prepare:
  extends: .deploy
  stage: test
  script:
    - LB_ADDRESS=$(kubectl get services ingress-nginx-controller --output jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
    - APP_HOST=finenomore-dast.$LB_ADDRESS.sslip.io
    - helm upgrade --install $DAST_NAME ./k8s/finenomore
      --set namespace=$DAST_NAME
      --set finenomore.image=$IMAGE_NAME
      --set finenomore.imagePullSecrets=gitlab-credentials --atomic
      --set finenomore.ingress.host=$APP_HOST
    - echo "APP_ADDRESS is $APP_HOST"
    - echo "APP_ADDRESS=$APP_HOST" >> app.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: app.env
```

Job log:
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2C89.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the k8s events. The deployment has been rolled back due to atomic helm feature.